# FTP download progress bar in batch file

Tags: batch-file, download, ftp

I wonder if there is a possibility the code below to enable a progress bar or percentage counter to check the progress of download, however alternativar not seen since the download is being executed by the FTP client.

Follows the code:

```
ECHO OFF
Color 17
Setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CLS
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO . Selecione o numero desejado no menu abaixo  .
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Atualizar Frente/Retaguarda
ECHO 2 - Atualizar Rgourmet
ECHO 3 - Exit
ECHO.
SET /P M=Selecione 1, 2, ou 3 e pressione ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO FRENTE
IF %M%==2 GOTO RGOURMET
IF %M%==3 GOTO SAIR

:FRENTE

@ echo off

echo open 177.125.217.138>>frente.ftp
echo ****>>frente.ftp
echo ****>>frente.ftp
echo hash>>frente.ftp
echo cd atualizador>>frente.ftp
echo binary>>frente.ftp
echo get "libx12.dll">>frente.ftp
echo get "rjkmonitor.exe">>frente.ftp
echo get "rjkini.exe">>frente.ftp
echo quit>>frente.ftp
@ echo off

echo off taskkill /F /IM rjkpdv.exe > NUL
echo off taskkill /F /IM libx12.dll > NUL
echo off taskkill /F /IM rjkretaguarda.exe > NUL

ftp -v -i -s:frente.ftp

if exist macro.txt (
    rjkpdv.exe /a
    rjkini.exe
) else (
    del rjkretaguarda.exe
    ren libx12.dll rjkretaguarda.exe
    rjkretaguarda.exe /a
    rjkini.exe
)
del frente.ftp
cls
GOTO MENU

:RGOURMET

@ echo off
taskkill /F /IM rgourmet.exe
taskkill /F /IM rmt.exe
echo open 177.125.217.138>>rgourmet.ftp
echo ****>>rgourmet.ftp
echo ****>>rgourmet.ftp
echo hash>>rgourmet.ftp
echo cd atualizador>>rgourmet.ftp
echo binary>>rgourmet.ftp
echo get "rgourmet.exe">>rgourmet.ftp
echo get "rmt.exe">>rgourmet.ftp
echo get "rjkini.exe">>rgourmet.ftp
echo quit>>rgourmet.ftp
@ echo off

ftp -v -i -s:rgourmet.ftp
    rgourmet.exe /asgb
    rjkini.exe

del rgourmet.ftp
cls
GOTO MENU

:SAIR
exit
```

Comment: How do you expect the batch file to determine the file sizes such that it can monitor the downloads and determine the percentage completed.

Comment: Immediately change your password, you have posted it in public!

Comment: thanks for listening friend @MartinPrikryl what I wanted, I have done the test and it worked.

I will change the password FTP, although it is a basic test only.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build-in Windows command-line FTP client (`ftp.exe`) cannot display progress of the transfer. All it can do, is what you already get with the `hash` command.

---

You have to use another FTP client to get percentage progress.

For example with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/), you get the percentage progress by default.

```
winscp.com /command ^
    "open ftp://rjk:password@177.125.217.138/" ^
    "cd atualizador" ^
    "get libx12.dll" ^
    "get rjkmonitor.exe" ^
    "get rjkini.exe" ^
    "exit"
```

See a [guide for converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

[image: WinSCP progress display]

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Thank @MartinPrikryl